Merge and sort while remembering types and (maybe) also positions
I have two std::vector<double> v1, v2 already sorted and without duplicates (for double's ==). Let's say that the numbers in v1 are of type 1 and that the numbers in v2 are of type two. How can I merge v1 and v2 sort and remove duplicates into a std::vector<double> while retaining types ?
For instance if v1 = {2.3, 8.9, 10.0, 13.0} and v2 = {2.3, 4.4, 7.6, 10.0, 11.4, 12.6, 13.0} I would have v3 = {2.3, 4.4, 7.6, 8.9, 10.0, 11.4, 12.6, 13.0} and let's say a vector of types v3types = {3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3} where type v3types[i] == 3 says that v3[i] belongs to both v1 and v2.
What if I would moreover like to keep the information about the positions of v3's elements in the original vectors -- hence needing two indexes for elements of type 3 ?
(Ideally I would prefer to rely on the STL. Also, performance is important but not that important as this will be executed only one time in an execution context which needs performance and where other ram+cpu intensive computations are executed.)

@MSalters why what ? Why did I mention "for double's ==" ? (I just wanted to say that v1 v2 where sorted for the naturel "order" on double, not for anything else.) In fact I my real setup I have another type than double for which == is perfectly well defined and not prone to rounding errors, just wanted to give a simple example, for fell in an obvious trap

std::vector<double> v1{ 2.3, 8.9, 10.0, 13.0 };
std::vector<double> v2{ 2.3, 4.4, 7.6, 10.0, 11.4, 12.6, 13.0 };

std::map<double, int> m;
for (auto v : v1) m[v] |= 1;
for (auto v : v2) m[v] |= 2;

std::vector<double> v3;
std::vector<int> v3types;
for (const auto& [value, type] : m) {
    v3.push_back(value);
    v3types.push_back(type);
}


For performance, you can add v3.reserve(m.size()); v3types.reserve(m.size());. This is not particularly efficient though, because m[v] is O(log N).

Of course, the iterator solution is more efficient. I just wanted to offer something compact.

What you basically need is to implement std::set_union (which merges two already sorted ranges and eliminates duplicates) except that you place information about which range an element belongs to instead of copying the element itself.
You could just grab the reference implementation from cppreference and replace std::copy with std::fill_n and copies of values with storing 1 and 2 where needed.
Here is a modified version which produces just the indices:
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt>
OutputIt union_indices(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
               InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
               OutputIt d_first)
{
    for (; first1 != last1; ++d_first) {
        if (first2 == last2)
            return std::fill_n(d_first, std::distance(first1, last1), 1);
 
        if (*first2 < *first1) {
            *d_first = 2;
            ++first2;
        }
        else if (*first1 < *first2) {
            *d_first = 1;
            ++first1;
        }
        else {
            *d_first = 3;
            ++first1;
            ++first2;
        }
    }
    return std::fill_n(d_first, std::distance(first2, last2), 2);
}

// Usage:
const std::vector<double> v1{ 2.3, 8.9, 10.0, 13.0 };
const std::vector<double> v2{ 2.3, 4.4, 7.6, 10.0, 11.4, 12.6, 13.0 };

std::vector<double> v3;
std::set_union(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(v3));
// v3 is now {2.3, 4.4, 7.6, 8.9, 10.0, 11.4, 12.6, 13.0}

std::vector<int> v3types;
union_indices(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(v3types));
// v3types is now {3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3}

You can also produce a merged range and the indices at the same time if you simultaneously store the merged elements in one output iterator, and the indices in another.
Note that relying on exact equality between floating-point numbers is a bad idea, and that's what you're doing here.
You might end up with v1 and v2 storing two distinct values very close to 2.3 for example, but not exactly 2.3, and then they wouldn't be detected as duplicates of each other.
